# jQuery just clone VALUE element

Tags: jquery, html

I need to just clone a element's value to an another element

```
<a id="button" href="">Google</a>
```

I want print value on div

```
 <div id="destination">Google</div>
```

**jQuery** : With this, all `a` tag have been cloned ! I want just clone the value of element !

```
 $("#button").clone().appendTo('#destination');
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`clone()`** create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

However there are several ways you can achieve this

**1: [Using html() jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/html/)**

```js
$('#destination').html($('#button').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button" href="">Google</a>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

**2: [Using text() jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/text/)**

```js
$('#destination').text($('#button').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button" href="">Google</a>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

Comment: @BijanZand Glad to help :)